# How to calculate time intervals in SAS using dtdate format

Tags: date, sas, format, intervals

I have a SAS data set that has a date of birth (dob) variable in the dtdate9. format, so for example it shows as "01JAN2020".

I'm looking to create a new variable called 'Age' which calculates the age from this date, so how many year intervals since today's date. How would I do this?

Comment: Please remember to show what you have tried per SO guidelines [ask]. https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2011/07/12/computing-age-in-sas-9-3/

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
proc sql;
    create table have
    (dob num format=dtdate9.
    ,age num
    )
    ;
    insert into work.have
    values(0,.)
    ;
quit;

data want;
    set have;
    age=int(intck('year',dob,%sysfunc(date())));
run;
```

This link is helpful:
https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/How-to-convert-no-of-days-to-years-months-days-format/td-p/386885

Comment: YRDIF() function includes an AGE option and you do not need %SYSFUNC() around the date() portion.